# PNG aren't displayed but SVG are. Why?

Tags: html, svg, drupal, png

I face off an issue about I can't find a fix.
On https://provence-formation.fr/ , Drupal 9, but also on Drupal 8 websites. I encounter a weird issue for images at the bottom of the page. PNGs aren't display but SVG are. On Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Someone could explain to me why ?
Thanks

Comment: For the png you have an extra **en** in the url. You need https://provence-formation.fr/sites/default/files/webfm/deco/logo_qualiopi_print_2021-06.png instead of https://provence-formation.fr/en/sites/default/files/webfm/deco/logo_qualiopi_print_2021-06.png

Comment: ok, that would come from the language negociation so...I go to see this more in details. Thanks

Comment: bad way. The path is relative, so the language is added after. Perhaps I could to avoid adding the language to image.

Comment: try using an absolute path

Comment: it come from the Pathologic filter https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic , whithout it, images are dipslayed, language prefix isn't added to the image path.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by patching the module. https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic/issues/3270030#comment-14538399